# Crosscompile GStreamer, Farstream for ARM11

Tags: c, arm, cross-compiling, gstreamer

I'm looking for a way to crosscompile GStreamer, Farstream and a small example using those libraries. I need to know a few things:

- What is the best way for crosscompiling those libraries for ARM11? I have been searching some information in Google and the solution has something to do with installing an arm compiler (that was already obvious) and then playing with `./configure`, but I'm not really sure what exactly should be passed as parameters.
- Once compiled the libraries, how can I *install* them in the ARM11 device? I mean, what's the next step after running `./configure <options for arm11>` and `make`?
- How can I link the example with the libraries that I compiled for the ARM11 device instead of the libraries installed in my system?

Regards

EDIT

Sorry for not saying. I'm working on Arch Linux x64 and the target device is running Linux too.

Comment: Are you crosscompiling for Linux?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for the confusion, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use scratchbox2. The project itself aims at cross compilation situation like what you asked especially involve the ./configure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In fact I'm already using it and I have some success :)   I just forgot to mark that question as closed, but as you took the time to answer me I'll accept your answer as valid :)